# Returning the True value from a SwitchListTile?

Tags: flutter

This is a noob question but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

I have 3 SwitchListTile where only one can be true at any given time - but I am unsure how to tell my code which one the user has selected as true so that I can pass a String to another object in order to do something else.

I have main.dart where I call colorswitch1.dart (which determines which color selection the user wants, i.e: green OR Blue OR Red OR yellow, etc).

The UI component works fine

I've looked into future variables and Navigator but I am unsure of what the correct answer is...or rather one that can work lol

My SwitchListTile looks like this:

```
    child: SwitchListTile(
            title: const Text('Color'),
            value: _anycolor,
            activeColor: Colors.black,

            onChanged: (bool value) {
              setState(() {


                if(value = true){
                  _anycolor = value;
                  _greyscale = false;
                  _transparent = false;
                  toRet = '';

                }


              });
            },
            //secondary: const Icon(Icons.color_lens),
          ),
```

`toRet` is just a String that I am trying to return back to the main.dart where I could have a variable called 'String Selection'

Or what is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

use List of bool to keep result of SwithListTile and a callback for to reset selection after click switch.

callback code snippet, _finalSelection have the result

```
void switchCallback(bool value, int index) {
    setState(() {
      for (var i=0; i<choice.length; i++) {
        choice[i] = false;
      }

      print(' click ${index}');
      choice[index] = value;

      _finalSelection = ' index ${index}  {$value}';
      print(' final selection ${_finalSelection}');
    });
  }
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This Widget is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: MyStatefulWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}


String _finalSelection = "";

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {

  static List<bool> choice = [false, false, false];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: SwitchListTile(
            title: const Text('Lights 1'),
            value: choice[0],
            onChanged: (bool value) {
              switchCallback(value, 0);
            },
            secondary: const Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline),
          ),
        ),
        Center(
          child: SwitchListTile(
            title: const Text('Lights 2'),
            value: choice[1],
            onChanged: (bool value) {
              switchCallback(value, 1);
            },
            secondary: const Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline),
          ),
        ),
        Center(
          child: SwitchListTile(
            title: const Text('Lights 3'),
            value: choice[2],
            onChanged: (bool value) {
              switchCallback(value, 2);
            },
            secondary: const Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void switchCallback(bool value, int index) {
    setState(() {
      for (var i=0; i<choice.length; i++) {
        choice[i] = false;
      }

      print(' click ${index}');
      choice[index] = value;

      _finalSelection = ' index ${index}  {$value}';
      print(' final selection ${_finalSelection}');
    });
  }
}
```

[image]

execution information, you can change _finalSelection per your request

```
I/flutter ( 9216):  click 2
I/flutter ( 9216):  final selection  index 2  {true}
I/flutter ( 9216):  click 1
I/flutter ( 9216):  final selection  index 1  {true}
I/flutter ( 9216):  click 1
I/flutter ( 9216):  final selection  index 1  {false}
I/flutter ( 9216):  click 0
I/flutter ( 9216):  final selection  index 0  {true}
I/flutter ( 9216):  click 1
I/flutter ( 9216):  final selection  index 1  {true}
I/flutter ( 9216):  click 2
I/flutter ( 9216):  final selection  index 2  {true}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding setState((){});

```
 if(value = true){
   setState((){
    _anycolor = value;
    _greyscale = false;
    _transparent = false;
    toRet = '';
   }); 
 }
```